# Stored Procedure Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

It says that I have an error on the

```
 where ResourceID = @ResourceID
```

But I don't see anything with it.

See the whole query below. I ran this independently and it works.

This is the independent query that I just ran.

**INDEPENDENT QUERY**:

```
  Select  
      ResourceID, OrganizationID 
  from 
      ResourceOrganization
  where 
      ResourceID = 'FA11343' 
      and EffectiveDate = (select MAX(EffectiveDate) 
                           from ResourceOrganization 
                           where ResourceID = 'FA11343' 
                           group by ResourceID)
```

**ACTUAL QUERY WITH ERROR INVOLVED**:

```
 if @ResourceID <> ''
 begin
     insert into #Resources (resourceID, OrganizationID)
        Select  
            ResourceID, OrganizationID 
        from 
            ResourceOrganization
        where 
            ResourceID = @ResourceID
            and EffectiveDate = (select MAX(EffectiveDate) 
                                 from ResourceOrganization 
                                 where ResourceID = @ResourceID
                                 group by ResourceID)
 end

create procedure [dbo].[ExportResourceTime]
    @ResourceID nvarchar(30),
    @OrgUnit nvarchar(15),
    @TimeDetail int,
    @ExpenseDetail int,
    @FromDate Datetime,
    @ToDate Datetime,
    @IncludeID int,
    @TimeTypeGroup int
as
BEGIN 
 --SET @ResourceID = 'DM2699'
 --SET @OrgUnit = ''
 --SET @TimeDetail = 3
 --SET @ExpenseDetail = 1
 --SET @FromDate = '2013-11-01'
 --SET @ToDate = '2013-11-30'
 --SET @IncludeID = 1
 --SET @TimeTypeGroup = 21

/************************** SECTION 1 - CREATING A TEMP TABLE TO GET TIME AND EXPENSE DETAILS  ********************/
create table #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
(
    IDNo int,
    OrderBy1 varchar(60),
    ItemDate datetime,--MOD005
    RevenueTypeCode varchar(24),
    TimeType varchar(24),
    ProjectCode varchar(20),
    taskUID int,
    OutlineNum varchar(60),
    taskname varchar(60),
    activitycode varchar(24),
    ActivityDesc varchar(60),
    ResourceID varchar(24),
    OrganizationID nvarchar(15),
    EffectiveDate datetime,
    firstname varchar(60),
    lastname varchar(60),
    ExpenseTypeCode varchar(24),
    ExpenseTypeDesc varchar(60),
    Hours decimal(8,2),
    Rate decimal(8,2),
    Total decimal(20,8),
    Descr varchar(256), --MOD005 DM Added col for relevant detail for Expenses
    TimeTypeCode nvarchar(10)
 )
--GW: move this bit to the top--DONE

create table #Resources
(
ResourceID nvarchar(30),
OrganizationID nvarchar(15),
EffectiveDate datetime
)

--select * from #Resources

--insert into #Resources
-- 1. @resourceid is present then only 1 single record in the table
-- 2. if @orgunit  is present, find all resourceID belongs to this orgunit and insert into #resources

if @ResourceID <> ''
 begin
 insert into #Resources (resourceID,OrganizationID)

  Select  ResourceID,OrganizationID from ResourceOrganization
  where ResourceID = @ResourceID
  and EffectiveDate = (select MAX(EffectiveDate) 
  from ResourceOrganization 
  where ResourceID = @ResourceID
  group by ResourceID)
  end

 if @OrgUnit <> ''
 begin
 insert into #Resources (resourceID,OrganizationID)
  Select  A.ResourceID,A.OrganizationID from ResourceOrganization a
  where A.OrganizationID like '' + @OrgUnit + '%'
  and A.EffectiveDate = (select MAX(EffectiveDate) 
  from ResourceOrganization 
  where ResourceID = A.ResourceID 
  group by ResourceID)
  end 


-- get actual time - REGULAR
insert into #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
select      
Case when @IncludeID = 1 then b.timeID else '' end, --mod 07
e.lastname + e.firstname, 
case when @TimeDetail = 2 then g.enddate else (case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.TimeEntryDate else null end) end,--MOD005
'FEES',
'Regular',
b.projectcode,
b.taskuid,
f.outlinenum,
f.taskname,
b.ActivityCode,
c.ActivityDesc,
b.resourceID,
RES.OrganizationID,
e.firstname,
e.lastname,
'','', -- expense
sum(isnull(b.StandardHours,0)), -- MOD003 - added in isnull's
0,--h.StandardAmt,--b.NegotiatedChargeRate, --MOD005 Change to NegotiatedChargeRate from StandardChargeRate
0,--sum(isnull(b.StandardHours,0)* IsNull(h.standardAmt,0)),--sum(bd.BilledAmt),--MOD005 Change from BillableAmt feild (was incorrect for adjustments)
case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.invoicecomment else '' end,--MOD005
case when @TimeTypeGroup = 2 then b.TimeTypeCode else '' end--MOD008

from time b 
join activity c
on b.activitycode = c.activitycode
join resource e 
on b.resourceID = e.resourceID
join project p 
on b.ProjectCode=p.ProjectCode 
and p.RevisionStatusCode='A'
join task f 
on b.projectcode = f.projectcode 
and b.taskuid =f.taskuid 
and f.revisionnum = p.RevisionNum
join SMECWeekEnding g   
on b.TimeEntryDate between g.StartDate and g.EndDate
join #Resources RES
on b.ResourceID = RES.ResourceID
--left join ratesetresource h on h.resourceid = b.resourceid
where       --b.projectcode = @PROJECTCODE and
b.statuscode in ('A','V','T')
and b.TimeEntryDate >= @FromDate
and b.TimeEntryDate <= @ToDate
and Isnull(b.StandardHours,0) <> 0
and b.resourceid in(Select ResourceId from #Resources)

--GW: need to filter by resources here      

group by  
b.projectcode,
b.taskuid,
f.outlinenum,
f.taskname,
b.ActivityCode,
c.ActivityDesc,
b.resourceID,
RES.OrganizationID,
e.firstname,
e.lastname,

case when @TimeDetail = 2 then g.enddate else (case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.TimeEntryDate else null end) end,--MOD005
case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.invoicecomment else '' end,
Case when @IncludeID = 1 then b.timeID else '' end, --mod 07
case when @TimeTypeGroup = 2 then b.TimeTypeCode else '' end--MOD008
having sum(isnull(b.StandardHours,0)) <> 0 


-- get actual time - OVERTIME
insert into #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
select      
Case when @IncludeID = 1 then b.timeID else '' end, --mod 07
e.lastname + e.firstname, 
case when @TimeDetail = 2 then g.enddate else (case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.TimeEntryDate else null end) end,--MOD005
'FEES',
'Overtime',
--GW: need projectcode here--DONE
b.projectcode,
b.taskuid,
f.outlinenum,
f.taskname,
b.ActivityCode,
c.ActivityDesc,
b.resourceID,
RES.OrganizationID as OrgUnit,
e.firstname,
e.lastname,
'','', -- expense
sum(isnull(b.OvertimeHours,0)), -- MOD003 - added in isnull's
0,
0,
case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.invoicecomment else '' end, --MOD005
case when @TimeTypeGroup = 2 then b.TimeTypeCode else '' end--MOD008
from time b 
join activity c 
on b.activitycode = c.activitycode
join resource e 
on b.resourceID = e.resourceID
join project p 
on b.ProjectCode=p.ProjectCode 
and p.RevisionStatusCode='A'
join task f
on b.projectcode = f.projectcode 
and b.taskuid =f.taskuid 
and f.revisionnum = p.RevisionNum
join SMECWeekEnding g   
on b.TimeEntryDate between g.StartDate and g.EndDate
join #Resources RES
on b.ResourceID = RES.ResourceID

where       
b.statuscode in ('A','V','T')
--and f.revisionnum = @latestapprovedrevision
and b.TimeEntryDate >= @FromDate
and b.TimeEntryDate <= @ToDate
and Isnull(b.OvertimeHours,0) <> 0
and b.resourceid in (select resourceid from #Resources)

group by  
--GW: projectcode here--DONE
b.projectcode,
b.taskuid,
f.outlinenum,
f.taskname,
b.ActivityCode,
c.ActivityDesc,
b.resourceID,
RES.OrganizationID,
e.firstname,
e.lastname,

case when @TimeDetail = 2 then g.enddate else (case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.TimeEntryDate else null end) end,--MOD005
case when @TimeDetail = 3 then b.invoicecomment else '' end,
case when @IncludeID = 1 then b.TimeID else '' end ,--mod 07
case when @TimeTypeGroup = 2 then b.TimeTypeCode else '' end--MOD008
having sum(isnull(b.Overtimehours,0)) <> 0

/*********************** SECTION 7: OUTPUT DATA TO CRYSTAL REPORT ************************/

-- return data to the Crystal report only if taskuid are in table 1

select * 
from #ItemisedTimeandMaterials
order by taskUID

drop table #Resources
drop table #ItemisedTimeandMaterials

END


GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Temp table #Resources requires that all fields have values.  In your Insert statement, you are not supplying EffectiveDate.  So either supply that filed, or change the definition of your Resources table to this:

```
create table #Resources 
(
  ResourceID nvarchar(30),
  OrganizationID nvarchar(15),
  EffectiveDate datetime null
)
```

Comment: Hi Brendan it didnt work. It prompted the same error, the error is in line 103 which is the "End" of the if @ResourceID <> '' begin.. insert into #Resource